# Use Lottie animations as a background

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, lottie

I am using a ImageBackground component in react native and it's a card component have some images to set on background and No i have to use Lottie design so i am not able to get how can i use lottie designs with Imagebackground. As if lottie designs are choosed then i will show lottie design other wise will show Imagebackground data.

```
<ImageBackground>
 <LottieView
        source={require('../path/to/animation.json')}
        colorFilters={[{
          keypath: "button",
          color: "#F00000"
        },{
          keypath: "Sending Loader",
          color: "#F00000"
        }]}
        autoPlay
        loop
      ></LottieView>
</ImageBackground>
```

How can i use lottie designs in the imagebackground.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by adding the Lottie animation in view with absolute position and with zIndex to make it a background View.

checkout the Github issue, this might help you.

https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/issues/307